Energy in projectile motion
When approaching a projectile motion problem using the conservation of mechanical energy, why do we use the speed of the object as a whole and not only the vertical component?
The horizontal motion of the object is not affected by the gravitational force, so my intuition is that it should not be included in the calculations in the conservation of mechanical energy and that we are only getting the vertical component of velocity in the term for the final kinetic energy of the object. Thank you in advance.

Look at the form of the kinetic energy and show to yourself that the horizontal component is just going to be a constant addition term that does not participate. That is, it is the same whether you take it out or leave it in. It is just convenient to leave it in.
